# Vim: How to create autocomplete/chooser from entries in buffer?

Tags: vim, autocomplete, buffer

Found out today that if you press Ctrl-Opt-Cmd-V in Textmate, it produces a cute little "chooser" dialogue in-place that allows you to page through your recent clipboard entries. It looks very similar to how CTRL-P and -N work in VIM, except it shows whole lines instead of simple word objects.

It seems like this would be doable in VIM — it already has a buffer full of entries (the YankRing buffer, for example), and it already has a chooser, but I can't think of where I'd look to start putting these two together. Any ideas?

(I know that YankRing already does this by opening a new window full of buffer content, but I wonder if there's a way to do it without all the window switching/closing/etc)

Answer (score 1):

Vim provides two user-defined insert completion mechanisms: User defined completion and Omni completion. You can read about them here:

```
:help compl-function
:help compl-omni
:help complete-functions
:help 'completefunc'
:help 'omnifunc'
```

I've never used these myself, but since you asked for where to start looking, that's it. You may also want to read this section,

```
:help ins-completion
```

for an explanation of Vim's various built-in insert-mode completion mechanisms, which may help you avoid writing your own. I didn't see a predefined mechanism for selecting from clipboard entries, however. You can insert from previous deletions with a little work by using `:registers` to view the available registers and then inserting the contents of the desired register with Ctrl-R followed by the register name. See

```
:help :register
:help registers
:help i_CTRL-R
```

Comment: The "previous deletions" register is my biggest VIM complaint, because VIM throws everything I delete in there along with things I purposefully yank. Using :reg is pretty inefficient, so I've been using YankRing instead to simulate an emacs-like killring behavior.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is probably a bit OT but I prefer to have a system-wide clipboard manager as this functionality is useful in many contexts. Here are the ones I'm using with the exact same keyboard shortcut for each:

- On Mac OS X, [ClipMenu](http://www.clipmenu.com/).
- On Ubuntu, [Parcellite](http://parcellite.sourceforge.net/).
- On Windows, [CLCL](http://www.nakka.com/soft/clcl/index_eng.html).